# batch response: Git LFS is disabled for this repository?

Tags: github, git-lfs

Now, github provide free private repo to user. So, I create a private repo and try to use `Git LFS`.

When I try to push files to remote, got this error:

```sh
batch response: Git LFS is disabled for this repository.
batch response: Git LFS is disabled for this repository.
batch response: Git LFS is disabled for this repository.
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/100), 0 B | 0 B/s, done
batch response: Git LFS is disabled for this repository.
batch response: Git LFS is disabled for this repository.
batch response: Git LFS is disabled for this repository.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/mrdulin/programming-ebooks.git'
```

Is that means that private repo does not support `Git LFS`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading this issue: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2481

I contact `support@github.com`, they solved my issue. Here is the email content:

> Hello there,
>
> Thanks for writing in and I'm sorry for the trouble. I've just rebuilt your Git LFS usage and it's now re-enabled on your account.
>
> Thanks,
>   Steve

Now, I can use `git-lfs`.

```
Connection to github.com closed by remote host. 6.0 MB/s
Uploading LFS objects:  51% (275/540), 5.5 GB | 5.2 MB/s
```

Comment: It looks like the `support@githubcom` has been replaced by https://support.github.com/contact

Answer (score 2):

for anyone facing this issue and visiting here for solution , I found the solution by coincidence and I have no explanation why it worked. Just uninstall git lfs before pushing and it works.

```
git lfs install --skip-smudge
git lfs track large_file_needed
git add .gitattributes large_file_needed
git commit -m "whatever"
git lfs uninstall
git push
```

Comment: weird ... but worked for me as well ^^

Answer (score 0):

Steps I followd

```
git lfs install
git lfs migrate import --include="*.csv" // example my large file is abc.csv
git lfs uninstall
git push -f origin <your-branch>
```